# REST API Which route should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I have a dilemma in my current project about my url. I would like opinions about how can I choice my route to access a resource.

For example, if a a USER can follow an other one, should I use `/users/{user_1_id}/follow/{user_2_id}` or `/users/follow/{other_user}` or `/users/folllow` with the id in parameters ?

I personally think that `/users/follow/{other_user}` think to be the best, but I don't know if it's the good choice.

Can I have your opinions ?

Comment: or `/users/{other_user}/follow/`

Comment: /users/{other_user}/follow/ and current user should be decided from api token

Comment: @rjackson I think it's hard to read that

Comment: please try to use acts_as_follower gem

Comment: This post is not about "a follow" issue. It's a question about how constructs my routes

Answer (score 0):

As for REST-Services you may consider having your services "state-less"... Therefore I would suggest to add all parameters needed for the service to process the request.

```
/users/{user_1_id}/follow/{user_2_id}
```

It gives you a.) better readability and better understanding of the service based on it's API (the URL) and b.) you will be thankful if you've to replace that service in the future (no headaches about where all the needed information is, no caching involved, less side-effects)... Other team-colleagues don't need to know more details about the service ("is the user cached in the background", "or is there a hidden user-id in the cookie", etc.)